# Approximate Cell Doubling Time?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, theoretical-biology, cell-culture, cell-cycle

If I know it takes 12 min to occur in mitotic fibroblast cells and I count there are 32 dividing cells in the microscope slide out of a total population of 32034 cells, how do I calculate the approximate doubling time in hours?

My colleague says it should be around 200 hours. But I don't understand how they reached to this conclusion, can anyone explain this to me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, 32034/32 = ~1000
1000 / 5 = 200 hours

Because 12*5=60 min = 1 hour